# Open file from QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt

I am just trying to write a code to open file by clicking a link which is displayed in QTextBrowser. But file is not getting open instead it is displaying in QTextBrowser itself. Here is my code

```
void MainWindow::openTextEdit()
{
    QTextBrowser *p = new QTextBrowser();
    p->show();

    p->append("<a href = \"/home/winbros/Test.cpp\"> Link </a>");
    p->append("<a href = \"/home/winbros/Test.doc\"> Link </a>");
    p->append("<a href = \"/home/winbros/Test.xls\"> Link </a>");
    p->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
}
```

I am using QT creator. Guys please let me know to use anchor clicked in this sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the [anchorClicked](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextbrowser.html#anchorClicked) signal could be useful to you. It contains the URL of the clicked link as a `QUrl`.

**Edit:** OP asks for a usage example. I don't have time for that right now, but here's roughly what I would do:

1. Let the class that needs to open a file have a slot `foo` that takes a `const QUrl&`.
2. `foo` can use `QUrl::toLocalFile` to construct a `QFile` and open it.
3. Connect your `QTextBrowser`'s `anchorClicked` signal to `foo`.

Comment: If possible, could you please give me a piece of code on how to use it in this context? I have gone through link given by you, but cant make anything out it.